# Is it hard to line the rear crank on a 2012 Honda pilot

Tags: honda, timing-belt, camshaft, crankshaft, pilot

Crankshaft and front camshaft lined up, the rear won’t line up with the belt off and spark plugs out, should I force it or do the rear supposed to move with force

Answer (score 2):

When you have alignment concerns when doing a timing belt, never force anything. It's a good way to go from a $100 DIY job, to needing a complete engine overhaul.

This makes me wonder what you mean by "force it". I don't remember on the J-series engines, but the rear camshaft may have a lobe pushing a valve open (at least one of the lobes on one of the cams should be in this position at any give time during the camshaft rotation). With that in mind, you're going to feel some resistance to the valve spring pushing back on the cam lobe, which will make it a little bit harder to move. It could be, the cam has come out of time somewhat due to the pressure from the valve spring. You should be able to look at the lobes and valves when you are trying to turn it to see if that is the issue.